# How to change percentage label to be displayed on top of each bar?

Tags: r

```
SlackvsVoteBARper<-ggplot(data = anes_sm, aes(x= Slack1,  fill=votedrec)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), 
                label = paste0(round ((prop.table(..count..) * 100),1), '%')),  
            stat = 'count', 
            position = position_dodge(.9), 
            size = 8)+ 
  labs(x = 'Level of Slacktivism',
       y= 'Frequency',
       title = 'Relationship between Slacktivism and Voting', fill='Voted or Not')+
  theme_bw()
SlackvsVoteBARper
```

This is my current code and currently, the percentage labels are overlapping in a messy at the bottom. I want to show the percentage labels at the top.

Comment: There is the function `geom_text_repel` from the `ggrepel` package to prevent overlap of the labels.

Comment: Hi thanks where would I add geom_text_repel to my existing code?

Comment: Just Replace `geom_text` with `ggrepel::geom_text_repel`